# Ruby substring downcase

Tags: ruby, string

Is there more appropriate way to downcase a substring than this one?:

```
string[a..b] = string[a..b].downcase
```

Maybe something like this:

```
string[a..b].downcase!
```

For example:

```
string = "RubyChangedMyMind"

string[1..string.length] = string[1..string.length].downcase 
# this is working but i want to know if there is more short way to do this
# (indeces may be different)
# something like string[a..b].downcase!
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want to accomplish.  Can you show a sample string and what you would like the result to be?  This seems to be doing what is expected.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want?

Comment: [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) always returns a _new_ string (or `nil`). Changing that string therefore doesn't affect the original string. Depending on your use case, you could use `sub!` and a regular expression.

Comment: @Stefan, I may be missing your point. `String#[]` doesn't change modify the string, but [String#[\]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) does. After `string[1..string.length] = string[1..string.length].downcase`, `string #=> "Rubychangedmymind"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I was referring to `string[a..b].downcase!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make proc:

```
my_downcase = Proc.new { |str,n,m| str.chars.each_with_index.map{ |c,index| (n..m).include?(index) ? c.downcase : c }.join}
```

and call it whenever you want:

```
my_downcase.call(string,range_from,range_to)
```

for example:

```
string = "dsadaDAdasdsadDADADadsadADD"
new_string = my_downcase.call(string,0,11)
#=> "dsadadadasdsadDADADadsadADD"
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice idea!